# jquery form plugin in wordpress to upload an image file does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-forms-plugin

Trying to use the jquery [form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) in a worpress site .

HTML:

```
<form id="imageform" method="post"  action="<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/ajaximage.php " enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" >

Upload image:

<input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" value=""  />
</form>

<button value="&nbsp;Upload&nbsp;" class="btn_upload">&nbsp;Upload&nbsp;</button>   
    <div id='preview'></div><!-- end of id preview-->
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".btn_upload").click(function(){

        $("#preview").html(''); 

    $(".result_upload").html('<img src="'+loc+'/images/ajax-loader.gif"  alt="wait.."/>');


    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                            target: '#preview'

            }).submit();

            });

    });
```

ajaximage.php has

```
  $photoimg = trim($_POST['photoimg']);
  echo 'got it';
```

If I do not select any file , I get the result as expected. But if I select an image file then the error message says - "Undefined index: photoimg in line ...."

How to make it work correctly?

Comment: Have you tried $_FILES instead of $_POST? http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: no, but why to use that ?

Comment: because any files uploaded are referenced in $_FILES not $_POST

Comment: @ElliotLings, want to take your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried $_FILES instead of $_POST? http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

(When a file is submitted it is referenced inside $_FILES and not $_POST.)